# Question about sampling from pair-copula?! Why kendall tau and copula to describe dependencies at the same time?

Tags: copula

Pair-copula is the way to model higher dimensional data with high complex dependencies, using only 2 varialbes at a time. Sampling from pair-copula is quite complex and need a careful understanding. The algorithm is as follows (for c-vine of 3 variables):

$x_1$ = $u_1$  # Is that to start algorithm since our variables are all uniform!!

$x_2$ = $h^{-1} (u_2,x_1,\theta_{11})$ # h is conditional distribution function of $u_2$ given $x_1$ and $\theta_{11}$ is the parameter of copula family used to model the dependencies structures.

$x_3$ = $F(x_3|x_1,x_2) = h[h(x_3, x_1,\theta_{12}), h(x_2, x_1,\theta_{11}),\theta_{21}]$,

meaning that

$x_3$ = $h^{-1}$$[h^{-1} (u_3, h(x_2, x_1,\theta_{11}),\theta_{21}), x_1,\theta_{12})$.

Here is my understanding:

In the algortihm, they start by $x_1=u_1$?!!

while we know that:

$x_1$ = $F^{-1} (u_1)$?!

Is that because we need to have a start of our algorithm since our variables are uniforms (Also see the comment of Whuber)?.

since,

$x_1$ = $F^{-1} (u_1)$ .....(1)

$F(x_2 | x_1) = h(x_1,x_2;\theta)$ .....(2)

Then, from (1) and (2) we can get this:

$x_2 |x_1 = F^{-1}(u_2|u_1) = h^{-1}(u_2|u_1)$ ..... (3)

Then (that what I am understand but do not konow if it is correct or not),

since we want $x_2$ and since $x_1= u_1$ then we can get this:

$x_2$ = $h^{-1} (u_2,x_1,\theta_{11})$ is that correct?

However, I could not understand $x_3$ very well. Why we got $h(x_2,x_1,\theta_{21})$ instead of having it as inverse!!

Also, we know that copula depends on rank correlation (e.g., kendall tau). Kendall tau can use to find the correlation between two varialbes. Also, copula is a function used to model the dependencies between two variables, so why we need to find Kendall tau and from that we can find the parameter of copula (which control the dependenceis structure between two variables)?! I mean why we only get kendall tau as our method to model the dependece structure between the variables?? is that because kendall tau can only tell us the strength of the association where copula can help us to know the type of dependencies (e.g., upper or lower tails). Any help please?

Comment: Since "We assume that the variables $X_1, \ldots, X_4$ are also uniform," that answers your principal question.

Comment: I think that also. Since for simplification, we assume that all variable are uniform such that f(x) =x. Then, I think they consider $x_1$ = $u_1$ since they need to have a start. That is, they start the vine with $x_1$ then for $x_2$ they need to figure that using inverse conditioal distribution. but I do not know if that is correct or not?!

Comment: @whuber I edit my question and add futher comments and infromation about my whole concern and hope I can get a discussion or help to figure  it. Many thanks for your and all other people.